# Cannot implicitly convert type "int" to "System.EventArgs"?

Tags: c#

l'm fresh user of C# and l m trying to do some simple basic games to cover up basic things. l'm familiar with coding as l studied on python before. My problem is l can not convert some of buttons to "int". Some of buttons can be convertible but buttons (bn1,bn2,bn3...) are not convertible and give an error. if l use `Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text);`, it is working ,however, if l try to use `e=Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text);`, it does not work. How can l solve this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int say1, say2, say3, say4, say5, say6, say7, say8, say9;
        int a, b, c, d,e,f,g;


    int say = 0;
    float klm = 0;
    Random rastgele = new Random();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void islem()
    {

    }

    private void PLAYY_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        BT1.Text = rastgele.Next(1, 10).ToString();
        BT2.Text = rastgele.Next(1, 10).ToString();
        BT3.Text = rastgele.Next(1, 10).ToString();
        BT4.Text = rastgele.Next(1, 10).ToString();
        BT5.Text = rastgele.Next(1, 10).ToString();
        BT6.Text = rastgele.Next(1, 10).ToString();

        QUEMARK.Text = rastgele.Next(25, 100).ToString();
        TARGETBT.Text = rastgele.Next(100, 1000).ToString();

    }

    private void EXITT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void BT1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        a = Convert.ToInt32(BX1.Text);
        b = Convert.ToInt32(BX2.Text);
        c = Convert.ToInt32(BX3.Text);
        d = Convert.ToInt32(BX4.Text);
        e = Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text);


        if (a == 0)
        {
            BX1.Text = BT1.Text;
            BT1.Enabled = false;
            BT1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        }
        if (a > 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text) == 0) 
            {
                bn1.Text = BT1.Text;
                BT1.Enabled = false;
                BT1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }

            else
            {
                BX2.Text = BT1.Text;
                BT1.Enabled = false;
                BT1.BackColor = Color.Azure;
            }
        }

    }


 }
```

Comment: You have two different things named `e`.

Comment: As an aside, terminology does matter; you are not converting a button to an int; you are converting the button's text to an int.

Comment: Side note: please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - posting wall of code as a question is not welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your method BT1_Click contains a parameter called e of type EventArgs

In the body of your method, you have another variable called e into which you want to assign `Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text);`

To achieve what you want to do you need to refer to your class variable e, namely "this"

```
this.e = Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) as the qualifier to denote that you mean the class field `e` and not the parameter `e` passed into the method.

```
this.e = Convert.ToInt32(bn1.Text);
```

---

Alternatively you can give the method parameter `e` a different name like `args`.

```
private void BT1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `int mynumber=Int32.Parse(txtSomeTextBox.Text);`